# awk or sed to remove text after last digit in field

Tags: awk, sed

In the `tab-delimited` file below I am trying to remove the text after the last digit in `$1`. I have tried two`sed` commands and gotten close but not the desired output. I don't know if I am using the best approach.  Thank you :).

**file**

```
chr7:55249071C>T    EGFR
chr7:55242469_55242477delTTAAGAGAAG EGFR
```

**desired output**

```
chr7:55249071   EGFR
chr7:55242469_55242477  EGFR
```

**sed**

```
sed 's/[0-9]//g' file

chr:C>T EGFR
chr:_delTTAAGAGAAG  EGFR

sed 's/[a-z]//g' file

7:55249071C>T   EGFR
7:55242469_55242477TTAAGAGAAG   EGFR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negated character class and anchoring to delete only at end of string

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {sub(/[^0-9]+$/, "", $1)} 1' ip.txt
chr7:55249071   EGFR
chr7:55242469_55242477  EGFR
```

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}` to set input and output field delimiter as tab
- `sub(/[^0-9]+$/, "", $1)` to perform substitution only for first field, this makes it much easier to adapt for different fields compared to `sed`
- `1` idiomatic way to print contents of `$0`

Answer (score 1):

If it's guaranteed that your input has only two tab delimited fields you can use this:

```
sed 's/[^0-9]\+\t/\t/' file
```

Comment: Thank you both :)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\(.*[0-9]\)\S\+/\1/' file
```

Match up to the last numeric digit and store as a back reference and remove any non-space characters following it.